# Google app engine: reverse reference lookups

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Is reverse referencing possible in Google app engine? I am using app engine patch to develope an application and my model is something like:

```
class Portfolio(db.Model):
   user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
   pic = db.BlobProperty()
```

Now, If I have the user object, is it possible to retrieve the pic associated with the users portfolio? i.e. the reverse reference from the User to Portfolio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can access the pics, via:

```
user = User()
pics = user.portfolio_set
```

You can change the default name (which is `modelname_set`) by passing the `collection_name` argument to the `ReferenceProperty` constructor. For example:

```
class Portfolio(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name="Portfolio")
```

See more information and examples here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html

Comment: Glad to help :) Get familiar with the SDK docs -- there are a lot of interesting and helpful comments there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
By default you can access users portfolio through user.portfolio_set.
Read here for more info: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/articles/modeling.html